# How to make an in-game button (with text) in Phaser?

Tags: dart, phaser-framework

I have made a PNG image which will be my button background. In the `preload()` of my relevant state I load that image. I want a way to have this image placed in the world and be able to set text onto it (and also be clickable but I guess that's a bit unimportant here because I know how to set up event handlers).

I thought I could manage something with

```dart
Text text = new Text(x,y,foo,style);
text.texture = <something>
```

but trying to, for example, create a `new Texture()` shows a warning "undefined class Texture" in DartEditor, and anyway (as far as I can tell?) `Texture` doesn't seem to allow giving a source image key/URL..

So could anyone with Phaser experience tell me how I can get an in-game button as I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I currently seem to have achieved more or less what I wanted (may have to tweak some values here and there but generally seems alright) with code like this

```dart
class MyState 
{
  preload() {
    //...
    game.load.image('key','$assetPath/button.png');
    //...
  }

  create() {
    Sprite temp2;
    temp2 = new Sprite(this.game, x, y, 'button');
    BitmapData bmp = game.add.bitmapData(temp2.width, temp2.height);
    bmp.draw(temp2);
    //Text positioning x,y in fillText() is just my choice of course
    bmp.ctx.fillText('Wait', bmp.width / 2, bmp.height / 2);
    game.add.sprite(game, someX, someY, bmp);
  }
}
```

EDIT: For what I'm doing there adding the bitmap to game cache wasn't needed; must've been something I was trying when trying to figure it out and forgot to delete.

So I needed to use the `BitmapData` class. My only little concern with this (although I'm not sure it really is an issue) is how when I create the `Sprite temp2` I am giving it a position but of course it is not used in the game, rather the output of drawing the sprite, and then text on top, to `bmp` is added as a sprite to the game. Does anyone know if there are any real implications of creating that first `Sprite` and leaving it like so? I'm just wondering because visually it appears it is not an issue since it is not appearing in the "game world".

Also, while this method seems just fine for me at the moment I'm curious as to whether there other ways, like something else that is somehow better and/or more preferred?

Comment: that is some strange looking JavaScript. Its cool, it looks like Java. I'm getting used to es6 and es7 features but I'm unfamiliar with being able to just declare a variable with a class like ```Sprite temp;```. My babel totally chokes and dies on that. EDIT: lol, just realized that  this is Dart.